# What is the difference of fetch api between edge function(cloudflare/vercel) which based on v8 and node environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, cloudflare, vercel

At present, some cloud service providers such as Vercel and Cloudflare both provide edge function computing running in v8 isolate, but when using the fetch api, sometimes a 403 error occurs, while there is no such problem when using node environment.

---

Example:

run

```
curl https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.mode=check_authentication
```

or fetch in nodejs, will get

```
ns:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
is_valid:false
```

but fetch in Cloudflare worker or Vercel edge function will get 403 Forbidden

Comment: V8 doesn't implement `fetch` at all, it's always provided by the embedder -> dropping "v8" tag.

Answer (score 0):

According to [cloudflare community](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/what-is-the-difference-of-fetch-api-between-cloudflare-worker-and-node-environment/409929), there’s no difference.

It might be that steam limits network traffic from cloudflare worker and vercel edge function.

But i still don't know why Steam makes this limit.